# Homework assignment with error with sentinel loops

Tags: sentinel

Ok, so I am working on this class assignment where I have to write a program that uses a sentinel value controlled loop to input student scores and displays the count of students and the average of all scores when a -1 is entered. A title is to be displayed when the program first begins. Valid score values are from 0 to 100. When a value in excess of 100 is entered, it is not to be included in the total and the number of students is not to be incremented. When a value of -1 is entered, the list is ended and the program displays the number of valid scores entered and the average score. If a -1 is entered as the first input, no error is to be reported and a message is to be displayed that no scores were entered.

Now, I was originally able to get the program to give me an output where it allowed me to enter the grades but what I realized was that when I entered "999" or "-1" the program didn't stop and average the grades I inputted from the keyboard and so I've been trying to fix it and now I'm at a stump and don't have a clue on how to fix it. I'm a beginner at this Java Programming and using NetBeans software. Honestly, I have to constantly look up what the errors mean because I don't have a clue. I could really get some help since my professor had to evacuate last week he hasn't been able to have access to his computers so I'm at this alone.
The errors I'm getting right now are:
C:\Users\sjccuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StudentsScoreReport\src\studentsscorereport\StudentsScoreReport.java:38: error: unclosed character literal
else (studentCount == '999');{
C:\Users\sjccuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StudentsScoreReport\src\studentsscorereport\StudentsScoreReport.java:38: error: not a statement
else (studentCount == '999');{
C:\Users\sjccuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StudentsScoreReport\src\studentsscorereport\StudentsScoreReport.java:38: error: 'else' without 'if'
else (studentCount == '999');{
C:\Users\sjccuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StudentsScoreReport\src\studentsscorereport\StudentsScoreReport.java:38: error: unclosed character literal
else (studentCount == '999');{
C:\Users\sjccuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StudentsScoreReport\src\studentsscorereport\StudentsScoreReport.java:40: error: class expected
studentCount = int.next();
C:\Users\sjccuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StudentsScoreReport\src\studentsscorereport\StudentsScoreReport.java:40: error: ';' expected
studentCount = int.next();
6 errors

HOW DO I FIX THIS LOL? please help me, I'm so behind in my class because I haven't been able to get this project done. Below is my entire code.

```
public class StudentsScoreReport {

public static final int SCORE_COUNT = 5;
     
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Define Constants
double studentCount= 0; //students inital grade
double totalScore = 0; // students grades combined
double averageScore;  // average score from the number of students
int scoreCount = 0;  // output score from the calculated average score
    
// create the Scanner object. 
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in); 
 
// INPUT: Title at the top of the out   
System.out.println ("Kristina Rosado's Students Score Report");
System.out.println ("Enter a students score, 0 - 100, 999 to quit");   //input score from keyboard

//  PROCESS: Read the scores for the first city 
//  NOTE: the program's score starts at 0, but people count from 1       
if (studentCount == 0 && totalScore == 0 ){
averageScore = (totalScore / studentCount);
} // users input -1 at the first time

else {
averageScore = totalScore / studentCount;
System.out.printf ("%d student scores were entered\n", studentCount);
System.out.printf ("\nThe average of score of %d students is %.2f", studentCount, averageScore);

else (studentCount == '999');{  
System.out.println ("Thank you for your entries");
studentCount = int.next();
}     
}
while (studentCount != -1){

if (studentCount < -1) {
System.out.print("Please try again");
System.out.printf ("Enter the score for the next student #%d: ", scoreCount+1); 
// input the next score 
studentCount = stdin.nextDouble();   
} else if (studentCount > 100) {
System.out.print("Please try again");
System.out.printf ("Enter the score for the next student #%d: ", scoreCount+1);
// input the next score
studentCount = stdin.nextDouble();
} // end of for loop
// end of for loop 
}          
System.out.println ("Illegal entry for score");{
System.out.println("There is no student score entered ");
averageScore = totalScore / scoreCount; 
System.out.printf("\nThe average score for %d students is %8.2f\n", scoreCount, averageScore);
}
```

}// end of public static void main(String[] args);
} // end of public class StudentsScoreReport;enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I just ask what language this is in. I can see multiple syntax errors but I just want to put it through an IDE first.

Comment: I want to help you, I just need a bit more info